# Simulate Casio S-VPAM calulator

Tags: code-golf, string, parsing

It is 20th anniversary of [Casio's S-VPAM calculators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casio_V.P.A.M._calculators) and it is worth celebrating.

Task: Process input string as Casio S-VPAM calculator does. The infix notation and precedence of mathematical operations must be followed. Angle values are expected in radians. Since there were multiple updates, `sin 15`, `sin15` and `sin(15` are equally parsed as `sin(15)` and spaces are thus ignored.

Input: String or Char array

Output: Array of 8-bit numbers representing the segments states on the [7-segment display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display)
[image]

```
      A B C D E F G DP | representation | visualization
blank 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  |   0 / 00       | " " or "_"
minus 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0  |   2 / 02       | "-"
   0  1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0  | 252 / FC       | "0"
   0. 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1  | 253 / FD       | "0." or "0,"
   1  0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0  |  96 / 60       | "1"
   1. 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1  |  97 / 61       | "1."
   2  1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0  | 218 / DA       | "2"
   2. 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1  | 219 / DB       | "2."
   3  1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0  | 242 / F2       | "3"
   3. 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1  | 243 / F3       | "3."
   4  0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0  | 102 / 66       | "4"
   4. 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1  | 103 / 67       | "4."
   5  1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0  | 182 / B6       | "5"
   5. 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1  | 183 / B7       | "5."
   6  1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0  | 190 / BE       | "6"
   6. 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1  | 191 / BF       | "6."
   7  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0  | 224 / E0       | "7"
   7. 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1  | 225 / E1       | "7."
   8  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0  | 254 / FE       | "8"
   8. 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  | 255 / FF       | "8."
   9  1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0  | 246 / F6       | "9"
   9. 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1  | 247 / F7       | "9."
  deg 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0  | 198 / C6       | "o"
 frac 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0  |  48 / 30       | "/"
      A B C D E F G DC | representation | visualization
```

Input string is split in substrings as follows:
`X` : number
 decimal separator is either dot or comma, whatever comes first. Using both results in `Syntax Error`
`n` : one-digit number or result in braces
`command` : string operator

Special commands:

- Power `X^n`: `X` to power `n`
- Root `nsqrtX`: `n`th root of `X`
- Exponent: `XEY` `X` times 10^`Y`
- Angles: `XD` return `X` degrees in radians; `XG` return `X` grads in degrees
- Degrees: `XdYdZd` return string in `MoNoXo` format. `M` is number of whole degrees(hours), `N`<60 number of whole minutes and `X` seconds (may be decimal) If part of command return as decimal value. `Xd` may be omitted returning `0oNoXo` string instead
- Goniometric functions `funX`: 'function of `X`. `-h` suffix triggers hyperbolic function `a-` prefix triggers inverse function.
- Logarithms: `lnX` natural logarithm of `X`; `logX` decadic logarithm of `X`
- Fractions: `X\Y`,`X\Y\Z`: If `X`and`Y`and`Z` are integers return "`A`/`B`" where `A` and `B` are lowest integers possible, otherwise return default format
- Combinatorics: `X!` Factorial of `X`; `XCY` [`Y`-combinations of `X`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination); `XPY` [`Y`-permutations of `X`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation). `X` and `Y` must be integer, otherwise return `"Syntax error"`
- Constants: `pi`, `e`
- Random number: `Ran#` return uniformally distributed value U(0,1)
- Absolute value: `AbsX`

Non-necessary zeros, multiplications and trailing brackets may be omitted

Test:

```
Input                   | Result HEX array                          | Result Visualized
1+6                     | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 E0 00 00 00 | "          7   "
sin-.5pi                | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 60 00 00 00 | "         -1   "
cosh180D                | 00 60 61 B6 F6 60 F6 B6 F2 DA FE 00 00 00 | " 11.59195328   "
piD                     | 00 00 F2 C6 FE C6 DA F7 E0 F2 C6 00 00 00 | "  3o8o29.73o   "
-25e-4sin 1-cos 59^(5-7 | 02 61 FC F2 60 B6 E0 E0 E0 66 F2 02 60 FC | "-1.031577743-10"
```

Rules:

Standard rules apply: Loopholes forbidden, the shortest answer in bytes win.

Comment: Hello and welcome to PPCG! I see potential in this challenge, but as it stands it appears a bit rough around the edges. You could use the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) to fine tune your challenge and get community input on best practices and standard rules.

Comment: I'd suggest adding a diagram to clarify which stroke a register corresponds to, e.g. the top stroke is denoted `A`.

Comment: @user202729 Thank you very much for your comments. I've removed the bonus part and updated the angles part. My old Casio has malfunctioning display and the new one has natural-VPAM. I'll process it soon

Comment: Regarding the "stack error" I am not sure about this limitation. I am sure there was a limit on the length of the input "string".

Comment: Hi, and Welcome to PPCG! It's your challenge so you're the boss... you can decide that the only limitations are the ones you outlined in the challenge, or make it more like a simulator by enforcing actual limitations/bugs. It's your decision, just clarify what your intent is and make sure to edit the question accordingly (ie "no need to enforce stach error for >23 nested parentheses" or "must throw a Stack Error when >23 nested parentheses".

Comment: @JayCe The challenge was intended to celebrate the S-VPAM calculators with all their features and bugs.

Comment: I'm temporarily vote to close the challenge as "unclear what you're asking", when it's clear enough I will retract the close vote or vote to reopen.

Comment: (summary of all comments above: remaining issues: 1. What should `x\y\z` do (what's `A` and `B`?) 2. What does a number displayed on the screen, such as `-1.031577743-10`, mean (last 3 digits are the exponent I suppose) 3. Stack error? 4.  `sin` -> `sin Ans`? 5. What exactly is the priority of the "special" operators? ||| some points that is clear enough but I believe is incorrect, it's up to you to decide to keep the original specification or change it: 1. `P` `C` or `!` on non natural should give `Math error`.

Comment: 2.  Decimal point is always `.`, not `,`. 3. I think the calculator use `sin¯¹` not `asin`. 4. I think `X°Y°` is interpreted as `X°Y°0°` not `0°X°Y°`, 5. The "`XG` return `X` grads in degrees" part doesn't look correct, I think it should be "in radians". )